# Tkinter updating matplotlib figure from different tk.Button in another frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm building a GUI using Tkinter for the first time and have run into a problem updating the data in a Matplotlib Figure using a button in a different frame.  Below is some generalized code to show the error I'm getting.

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class testApp():
    def app(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.create_frame1()
        self.create_frame2()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def create_frame1(self):
        frame1 = Frame(self.root)
        frame1.grid(row=0)
        (x, y) = self.create_data()
        f = plt.Figure(figsize = (5,2), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        lines1, = a.plot(x, y)
        f.tight_layout()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, frame1)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()

    def create_frame2(self):
        frame2 = Frame(self.root)
        frame2.grid(row=1)
        reEval = Button(frame2, text = "Reevaluate", command = lambda: self.reRand()).grid(sticky = "W")

    def reRand(self):
        (x, y) = self.create_data()
        ax = self.root.frame1.lines1
        ax.set_data(x, y)
        ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
        ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
        self.root.frame1.canvas.draw()

    def create_data(self):  
        y = np.random.uniform(1,10,[25])
        x = np.arange(0,25,1)
        return (x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = testApp()
    test.app()
```

When I run this code, I get an error:

> AttributeError: frame1

I think my problem stems from how I am referencing the frame containing the figure, itself, so I'm fairly certain this problem is arising from my lack of Tkinter experience.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more to do with using Python classes than Tkinter. All you really need to do is change all frame1 in create_frame1 to be self.frame1. Similarly in reRand, self.root.frame1 becomes self.frame1.

As it is the name "frame1" doesn't exist beyond the end of create_frame1, but if you save it as an attribute of self you can access it later.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured I had overlooked something simple.  After I make those changes, I get another error 'AttributeError: Frame instance has no attribute "lines1"'.  I'm guessing because this is a matplotlib figure, referencing that it a little more complicated..  Any ideas there?

Comment: It's basically the same thing - `lines1` is only accessible for the duration of `create_frame1`. (I think also you don't want to save `lines`, you want to save the axis.) Add `self.axis=a` to the end of `create_frame1`, so you can access it later, and change `ax = self.root.frame1.lines1` to `ax=self.axis`.

Comment: I'd also have a (re-)read of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html or http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes since the bits you're getting stuck on are really to do with how to store data in Python classes, rather than anything specific to Tkinter or matplotlib

Comment: Great comments and resources, DavidW.  Thank you!  I'll be back to upvote when I get my 15 reputation!